# What's the best way to select features independent of the model being used?

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am using **tensorflow's DNNRegressor** to model a multivariate **regression** problem. I want to form an optimal feature-set from a mixed bag of **categorical and continuous** features. What would be the best way to proceed? The reason, I want this approach to be independent of the model is because I couldn't find much about feature selection/evaluation in direct context of tensorflow.

Comment: Maybe you can give a little more context for the problem at hand. What you plan to achieve, what you tried, dataset description, etc.

Comment: I am trying to predict inventory for products for a certain time range in future. The problem is designed as a regression problem (with demand being target variable), having multiple inputs like product price, its brand etc. as features. We started with a set of features based on intuition and offline experience as to what affects demand. This set includes both numerical and categorical variables. Now, I want to add more features but need a way to derive the best set from existing and additional variables.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow is mostly library for machine learning algorithms. So, you need to use other libraries for preprocessing.
Scikit-library is good in many cases. You should try it, it contains the [feature selection methods](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html). I'm not sure about the categorical features, but if not you always can convert it to numerical ones.
They suggest:

> For regression: f_regression, mutual_info_regression

And for any problem, you can use their first method [VarianceThreshold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#removing-features-with-low-variance)